# Get first char of each line in textbox vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string, char

I know this should be easy.. BUT, every time I run this code, It tells me the first char of the first line THEN it returns "" for all following chars.....

```
Dim firstChar As Char

' Split on New Line
For Each strLine As String In TextBox1.Text.Split(vbNewLine)

    firstChar = strLine.First()

    If firstChar = "[" Then
      MessageBox.Show("I found it!")
    End If
Next
```

Comment: can we see your input data?

Comment: The reason they are "" is because you need to check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions(v=vs.110).aspx but also use a different method like the other answers pointed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Lines` value of the `TextBox` instead of splitting by new line character, like this:

```
Dim lines() As String
lines = TextBox1.Lines
```

Now you can loop through the string array and get the first character of each string, like this:

```
For Each line As String In lines
    ' Protect against strings that do not have a first letter to check
    If line.Length >= 1 Then
        Dim firstLetter As Char
        firstLetter = line.Substring(0, 1)
    End If
Next
```

Then you can put logic to check for the first letter being a certain value, like this:

```
If firstLetter = "[" Then
    MessageBox.Show("I found it!")
End If
```

---

Note: Above I was outlining the steps in isolation, but obviously you can combine some of these things together for a more concise solution, like this:

```
For Each line As String In TextBox1.Lines
    ' Protect against strings that do not have a first letter to check
    If line.Length >= 1 Then
        Dim firstLetter As Char = line.Substring(0, 1)

        If firstLetter = "[" Then
            MessageBox.Show("I found it!")
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I get an out of bounds exception on my char when it gets to the end.

Comment: @PeterBlack - answer to updated to protect against checking for a first letter in an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

```
  firstChar = strLine.Substring(0,1)
```

is more what im used to coding, never seen First before, not saying its invalid, but could be an issue?  also vbNewLine although is correct, I would split on char(10) or char(13) as sometimes its not both.   Also, whats inside strLine, in the debugger?